# std::basic_ostringstream exported by Boost unit test framework dll results in an "already defined symbol"-error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, dll

I use Visual Studio 2012. My setup is like this:

- some.lib links against some.exe
- some.lib links against some_test.exe

I use BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK when building some_test.exe. The results are the same using BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK for some.lib and test.exe.

I've built the some_test.exe, some.exe and some.lib with /MD (Multi-Threaded DLL). I've built the boost libs with runtime-link=shared. All are built and linked by VC11 (Visual Studio 2012).

The problem is, in some.lib, I'd like to use the local variable

```
std::ostringstream someStream;
```

The some.exe links fine. But when linking the some_test.exe, which dynamically links to the boost unit test framework (1.59) it gives me 3 errors (LNK2005):

## Errors

```
boost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-1_59.lib(boost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-1_59.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int)" (??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@H@Z) already defined in some.lib(some.obj) 
boost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-1_59.lib(boost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-1_59.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::str(void)const " (?str@?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@XZ) already defined in some.lib(some.obj) 
boost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-1_59.lib(boost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-1_59.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void)" (??_D?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAXXZ) already defined in some.lib(some.obj) 
some_test.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

The same happens when using msvc14 (Visual Studio 2015)

```
boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-1_59.lib(boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-1_59.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char>>::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int)" (??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@H@Z) already defined in some.lib(some.obj)
boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-1_59.lib(boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-1_59.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::str(void)const " (?str@?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@XZ) already defined in some.lib(some.obj)
boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-1_59.lib(boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-1_59.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void)" (??_D?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAXXZ) already defined in some.lib(some.obj)
some_test.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

## Strange Dependencies

I ran Dependency Walker on the file boost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-1_59.dll

```
??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@$$QEAV01@@Z
std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)
std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int)
```

or decorated:

```
??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@$$QEAV01@@Z
??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@1@H@Z
??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@H@Z
```

For comparison, I downloaded boost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-1_61.dll from

https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/

and that dll also exports those conflicting ostringstream symbols

```
 ??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@$$QEAV01@@Z
 std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)
 std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int)
```

So this seems normal behavior for the test framework. 
Though, for me it seems not a good idea to export those symbols to a dll.

I also did a `dumpbin /symbols some.lib`

There I find the conflicting symbols:

```
2AFC 00000000 SECT1183 notype ()    External   | ?str@?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@XZ (public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::str(void)const )
43D1 00000000 SECT16FA notype       Static     | $unwind$?str@?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@XZ
43D4 00000000 SECT16FB notype       Static     | $pdata$?str@?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@XZ

2AFA 00000000 SECT6AF notype ()    External    | ??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@H@Z (public: __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int))
43B6 00000000 SECT16F1 notype       Static     | $unwind$??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@H@Z
43B9 00000000 SECT16F2 notype       Static     | $pdata$??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@H@Z
43BC 00000000 SECT16F3 notype       Static     | $cppxdata$??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@H@Z
43BF 00000000 SECT16F4 notype       Static     | $stateUnwindMap$??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@H@Z
43C2 00000000 SECT16F5 notype       Static     | $ip2state$??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@H@Z

2B0E 00000000 SECTA3C notype ()    External    | ??_D?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAXXZ (public: void __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void))
4446 00000000 SECT1721 notype       Static     | $unwind$??_D?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAXXZ
4449 00000000 SECT1722 notype       Static     | $pdata$??_D?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAXXZ
```

As far as I understand, the (exact matching) symbols are marked "External" in some.lib. So they are not linked statically from the runtime into the some.lib, but dynamically.

## Known Workarounds

I can workaround the problem bei either using `std::stringstream` instead of `std::ostringstream` in the source of some.lib. I think I could live with that, but it would be hard to understand for any maintainer, why one would not be allowed to use ostringstream.

Alternatively, I could use the Linker-Flag `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` for some_test.exe and downgrade the Error LNK2005 to a Warning LNK4006. But I don't like perma-warnings, especially if they're only masked Errors.

## The Questions

What's the right way to use the boost_unit_test_framework and not get those linker errors?

Does boost intentionally export `std::basic_ostringstream` or should I submit a bug report?

Am I asking the wrong questions?

## Misc

The behavior of MSVC seems to have changed in Version 2010. Prior, there were no errors.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/191de00a-53c9-4bd9-9cb6-e844eb224ca2/lnk2005-when-using-stdostringstream?forum=vclanguage

After 8 days without answer or comment on SO, I opened a thread on the boost-user mailing-list. If an answer is found, I'll share it between SO and the mailing list, of course. http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2016/06/86332.php
(as of 17.08.2017 there is still no solution given in the mailing list either)

Now, 1 year later, I upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and get the same behavior.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you defined "BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK" symbol?

Comment: I had BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK defined for some_test.exe, but also rebuilt and linke with BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK set for both some.lib and some_test.exe. The 3 Error messages stay the same.

Comment: Have you tried with VS 2015? If the problem appeared in one compiler version, it may have disappeared in another.

Comment: @eh9 I just tried VS 2015, and got the same results. I added the linker error to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your pulling in two different C runtimes.
One through Boost and another one through your project.
Please check your project some_test.exe->Configuration Properties-> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library and try Multi-threaded DLL.

Comment: I checked the setting (for the hundredth time :-) ). It's already set to /MD in all projects.

Answer (score 0):

By Googling your issue, I have found following suggestions, if they can help you

---

Add to depend-projects macro with `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` and in main project add to linker input necessary libraries.
add /FORCE:MULTIPLE to the linker command line options.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70abkas3.aspx): "Use /FORCE:MULTIPLE to create an output file whether or not LINK finds more than one definition for a symbol."

Try this:

> The option `--build-type=complete` causes Boost Build to build all
>   supported variants of the libraries. Use `/MTd` for debug.

You can also consult [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: I tried your suggestion with BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB, but it doesn't change the errors. As I mentioned in the Question, /FORCE:MULTIPLE changes the permanent error to a permanent warning. I want my code to compile free of warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem due to trying many approaches to including boost unit tests in my project, and had duplicate inclusions of the include files and also duplicate definitions of my unit_test_main.